# Como fazer uma variavel guardar cada numero que um contador divide por um determinado numero?

Tags: visualg

Vamos supor que o numero seja o 12. Como fazer mostrar os numeros 1, 3, 6, 12 na frente?

Eu coloquei uma nota na frente da linha de codigo da qual eu estou falando.

```
algoritmo "Nums primos"
var
N,C,TotNums : inteiro
inicio
   C <- 1
   TotNums <- 0
   Escreval ("Digite um numero")
   leia (N)
   Enquanto (C <= N) faca
      Se (N%C = 0) entao
         TotNums <- TotNums + 1
      FimSe
      C <- C + 1
   FimEnquanto
   Se (TotNums > 2) entao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N," não é primo,pois ele é divisivel pelos numeros")///É nessa linha que eu quero colocar os numeros.
   senao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N," é primo.")
   Fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Você já aprendeu sobre arrays e/ou listas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem algumas formas de fazer isso. Se for necessário fazer alguma operação com estes números, o melhor seria criar um array (ou lista) e salvar estes valores.

Se a única intenção é mostrar estes valores, é possível criar uma `string` (`caractere` no VisualG) e ir concatenando os números nela.

Como VisualG é para iniciantes e, pelo código, me pareceu que você conhece *arrays*. Aqui vai um exemplo usando a segunda opção.

Obs.: Perceba que eu alterei o nome das variáveis `N` e `C` para `NumeroEscolhido` e `Contador`. Variáveis bem nomeadas deixam o código mais legível e mais fácil de entender.

```
algoritmo "Nums primos"
var
NumeroEscolhido, Contador, TotNums : inteiro
DivisivelPor : caractere
inicio
   Contador <- 1
   TotNums <- 0
   Escreval ("Digite um numero")
   leia (NumeroEscolhido)
   Enquanto (Contador <= NumeroEscolhido) faca
      Se (NumeroEscolhido % Contador = 0) entao
         TotNums <- TotNums + 1
         DivisivelPor := DivisivelPor + ", " + Contador
      FimSe
      C <- C + 1
   FimEnquanto
   Se (TotNums > 2) entao
      Escreval ("O numero ", NumeroEscolhido, " não é primo, pois ele é divisivel pelos numeros ", DivisivelPor)
   senao
      Escreval ("O numero ", NumeroEscolhido, " é primo.")
   Fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Abaixo uma versão em JavaScript, pra você poder executar aqui mesmo e ver que funciona.

```js
var numeroEscolhido = 12;
var contador = 1;
var totalNums = 0;
var divisivelPor = "";

while(contador <= numeroEscolhido){
  if(numeroEscolhido % contador == 0){
    totalNums += 1;
    divisivelPor += contador + ", ";
  }
  
  contador += 1;
}

if(totalNums > 2){
  console.log("O número " + numeroEscolhido + " não é primo, pois é divisível por " + divisivelPor);
}else{
  console.log("O número " + numeroEscolhido + " é primo");
}
```